# Redirect gallery folder to a gallery in another domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress blog with Nextgen gallery installed, I want to redirect all the gallery image request to another domain.I have duplicated all the images from site1 to site2 folder.

`http://site1.com/wp-content/uploads/gallery/folder/*.jpg`
to
`http://site2.com/gallery/folder/*.jpg`

please help me with the .htaccess redirect rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a wordpress blog with Nextgen gallery installed, I want to
>   redirect all the gallery image request to another domain.I have
>   duplicated all the images from site1 to site2 folder.

You have to make sure the custom rules don't get in conflict with WP own rule-set.

Assuming it is the standard one in one .htaccess file at root directory, replace it with the following one:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Add this line
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-content/uploads/gallery/folder  [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# Add this line
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/gallery/folder/([^.]+)\.jpg   http://site2.com/gallery/folder/$1.jpg [R=301,L,NC]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

#### Option:

For any file type, replace the last rule with this one:

```
# Add this line
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/gallery/folder/([^.]+)\.([^/]+)/?   http://site2.com/gallery/folder/$1.$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, the rule works great with wordpress installed locally with xampp.. But it's not working on a cpanel installed wordpress.

Comment: Check the .htaccess at WP install in the live server and modify the one in my answer accordingly, or update your question with it's content to be able to modify my answer.

Comment: thanks tested the rules on another wordpress installation and works great..may be something wrong with my other installation. will do a manual install and check..thanks for helping..

Comment: could u plz update the rules so that all the image extension work  .jpg,.png,.gif a wildcard entry if possible.